# Access network file from ASP.NET web handler's process?

Tags: asp.net, networking

I have the following setup:

IIS 8.0
a web handler call it test.ashx
Impersonation & Windows Authentication are both configured.  Kerberos is showing as the authentication type.

test.ashx uses the unmanaged API:    CreateProcessAsUser()  method to run "cmd.exe /c myScript.cmd"

I put statements in myScript.cmd and see that it is running as the requesting user as I need it to.  The problem I am experiencing is that the script cannot reference network files (either mapped drives or UNC path)

I need myScript.cmd to run as the requesting user and to be able to access network file resources.  How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I found one item that made a big difference on getting kerberos authentication to work, which is required to do impersonation and delegation.  In IIS Manager I had to choose the web site, then run the Configuration Editor.  Once it opened I had to choose the as from: DefaultWebSiteWeb.Config, and as the section: system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication.  Then set: useAppPoolCredentials = True.  Note: useKernelMode was already set to true.

Additionally, for the web site I have the following set for Authentication:
ASP.NET: Enabled
Windows Authentication: Enabled, Provider: Negotiate, Kernel mode enabled.

Now my ASHX web handler (in C#) can start a process as the user, run a .cmd file that accesses network resources.